# macOS Safari can not delete stored http digest password

Tags: macos, safari, password, http

I enter a site with HTTP authentication, and use my credentials, username and password, and selected "**remember password**" option.

After that, site is always accessible without login, which is ok. But then if I want for some reason (security, testing, switching user etc) to delete that password, to make Safari forgot it and show me the login window again - I can not find an option for deletion.

I have tried:

- Safari -> Preferences -> Passwords
- Safari -> Preferences -> Privacy -> Manage Website Data
- Keychain Access -> Passwords

But none of them contains website name. Also tested "**deleting all history and cookies**", and "force-kill Safari app" but password is still remembered somewhere.

By HTTP authentication I mean classic http protocol basic and digest authentication (used on some sites and often in routers and cameras)

What other preferences, settings for Safari and macOS i should try?

**update:** it seems that it was my own, newbie, fault (looking at 'local items' instead of 'login' portion of keychain passwords).

so HTTP credentials entered:

- without 'remember password' option are well cleared by '**force kill Safari app**'
- with 'remember password' option, data can be found and deleted inside '**Keychain Access -> Login -> Passwords**' list.

accepting below answer for good private-browsing tip (not sure if whole question is better to be deleted instead)

Comment: Have you tried deleting your cookies for the website?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @2br-2b yes, i have deleted all history with all cookies, same result, password is saved somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to clarify, most websites store their logins as cookies. The default configuration of browsers on any platform is to store the cookie until its expiry or until it is removed by the website or user. Because of this browsers will keep you logged-in by default between browser sessions.

What you have described most closely resembles **Private Browsing** where *Safari won't remember the pages you visited, your search history or your AutoFill information*, along with those login cookies. This can be enabled by going *File* > *New Private Window* or by using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, though this would have to be done each time you start safari as it will open a standard window by default.

Comment: ok, nice tip, however here i have checked my own site that use digest authentication without cookies for sure. And this considers for example "most router and camera interfaces" and many other examples where simple http basic and digest auth is used.

Comment: checked, private window WORKS WELL (asking for login finally). but still strange that simple browsing do not have delete option.